# How to specifiy custom Request handling into spring MVC controller?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, controller, annotations

I have defined an class for some specific handling:

```
public abstract class ListProvider {
  ...
  public abstract ResponseObject getResponse(RequestObject request) {}
}
```

I will create several derived class that I will define as services.
The purpose is to use it to create a json API using Jackson to deserialize the RequestObject and to serialize the ResponseObject. For example:

```
@Service
public class ClientListProvider extends ListProvider {
  public ResponseObject getResponse(RequestObject request) {
    return ...
}
```

I can use it in a controller like that:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/client")
public class ClientController {
    
  @AutoWired
  ClientListProvider provider;
  
  @PostMapping("/list")  
  public ResponseObject ResponseObject list(@RequestBody RequestObject request) {
    return provider.getResponse(request);
  }
}
```

But I would like to use it without the boiler plate, like:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/client")
public class ClientController {
 
  @PostMapping("/list")
  @Provider(ClientListProvider.class)  
  public list() {}
}
```

Or maybe:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/client")
@Provider(ClientListProvider.class,path="/list")  
public class ClientController {
}
```

Or something like that.

Do you know if there any way? If necessary I could replace the Request/ResponseObject by HttpServletRequest/Response or something else in the ListProvider interface.

Comment: Spring already does most of this sort of type conversion (and even data access) for you automatically, so it's unclear what problem you're trying to solve. Please rephrase the question more concretely instead of using "object", "client", and "list". Perhaps also take a look at Java generics, since it looks like your `ClientListProvider` (whatever that is) should possibly be generic (or just use Spring Data `Repository`).

Comment: The ClientProviderList implementation is not the point, it could be any request/response pattern, it is just an example. The point is: Is there an easy way to make the controller delegate the request handling to a service without writing boilerplate code?